# How do I fix my Intel Graphics drivers

Tags: drivers, hdmi, intel-nuc

I bought an Intel NUC and it works great on Windows but when I have two monitors on there is some tearing, especially for videos and when scrolling. On windows I could just update the drivers from the Intel website but they haven't provided anything for Linux.

From the output I pasted below is there anything that I could install to fix the issues? The dmesg command gives some error output in red but I don't know how to read it.

https://paste.ofcode.org/sNxXUztzdG9ayxMVeVmJBT

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/nuc/nuc-kit-nuc6i7kyk-features-configurations.html

```
[   14.443916] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: ELD buf size is 0, force 128
[   14.444000] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 0
[   14.573056] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[   14.581645] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[   14.696958] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
[   72.030265] [drm:intel_dp_link_training_clock_recovery [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
[   72.038858] [drm:intel_dp_start_link_train [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* failed to start channel equalization
[   72.165916] [drm:intel_cpu_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915_bpo]] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
```

Comment: Intel has a repository with updated drivers and also a graphical tool for the purpose. Whether or not the minor updates fix the issue remains to be confirmed. The wireless combo is another unrelated issue. Please do not post several question in the same question.

Comment: I did try to install those but didn't get too far. I updated ny ubuntu for this reason but then I found the instructions on how to install the drivers from this website too confusing. https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2017q2-intel-graphics-stack-recipe

Comment: You can try the tool (I'm almost sure you won't be able to use more complex methods): https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.5 but before using it make sure you read and follow to the letter what is mentioned in "Signatures - Ubuntu*". That done go ahead, download and install the .deb file as usual. Then run it like any other program and it will update the Intel drivers for you. No need to ever use the tool again, if there are newer versions at Intel's they will be installed along with other regular updates from then on.

Comment: There's an edit I proposed to your question that apart from minor corrections it also removes the part about the keyboard. Please open a new question for that issue and describe it the best you can and if it work in Windows and/or other computer please mention it.